# Script to open port in squid-std.conf file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am tring to create a script that can add a port configuration line to the squid-std.conf file.  My script requires two parameters, the first `$1` being http or https and then the second parameter `$2` would be the port number.  My logic so far in pseudo code:

1. Make sure there are two parameters.
2. Make sure `$1` is either http or https.
3. Make sure `$2` is a valid number.
4. Make sure `$2` is a valid value 0-65535
5. Now check to see if the port is already open.
   This is the part I am stuck at.

The `squid-std.conf` file contains many configuration lines but if the script is called with `http 80` I would need to check to see if there is a line similar to the following:

```
acl Safe_ports port 80 #custom port change 2012/08/02 15:00
```

Now because lines can be commented out by adding a `#` to the front of the line I want to make sure the `#` is not present at the front of the line.  Then if there is a `#` to the right somewhere remove that and everything to the right of that.

Now check to make sure these words exist `acl`, `Safe_ports`, and `80`.  and the `80` needs to not match for something like `280`, must just be `80`.  This is case sensitive so no need to check for uppercase or lowercase.

If everything matches then print on the screen that this port is already open.  If it is not found then I would need to make some code to add the line within the file and this can be done later.  I hope this is enough details.

Thank you

Comment: The creator of Perl needs help editing a file? (^:

Comment: provide squid.std.conf file as sample, i will give it a try to create script.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                         

SCHEME=http
PORT=80
SQUID_CONF=/path/to/squid-std.conf

if egrep -q "^ *acl +Safe_ports +port +$PORT " $SQUID_CONF
then
    echo "this port is already open."
fi
```